# MVC View Actions Call Different Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am converting a simple site from WebForms to MVC5.   It seems quite silly to have 15 different folders in *Views* each with their own Index.cshtml file.

Can I put all the views together in one folder, called *Home.cshtml*, *Contact.cshtml*, *Privacy.cshtml* but have those files each reference a different controller (i.e. the *HomeController.cs*, *ContactController.cshtml*, *PrivacyController.cs*)?

**UPDATE:** Currently, if I try to change my file structure so all the views are together in one folder called Pages, it tries to find a corresponding ActionResult in the *PagesController*.

I would like to have this file structure and be able to load my site using a URL like *www.example.com/privacy* and have it get the *Pages/Privacy.cshtml* view and automatically use the *PrivacyController.cs* or use *www.example.com/contact* and have it get the *Pages/Contact.cshtml* view and automatically use the *ContactController.cs*

Comment: so each controller going to  contain one action?

Comment: For the most part.   A few might have two actions.   But some of these controllers are rather complex, so I would like to keep them separated.

Comment: MVC uses [Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) in many cases.  This is one of them: the Controller name matches the view sub-folder name.  This allows you and future developers to quickly and easily find which controller your view is in etc.  By keeping the convention, you reduce bugs - to break the convention, you need to add configuration (in this case a routing entry as per existing answer) which will be prone to errors / future maintainability issues.  I recommend you keep the multiple folders or reconsider the controller structure.

Comment: Thanks for the very good explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use one controller and make multiple actions.Now you wil have one view folder.First change routeMap.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And inside the HomeController create action for each url

```
public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult Privacy()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

When you make request for www.example.com/privacy it will call privacy action.This way you can get what you want.

Comment: But then, I will end up with some super-sized Controller.    I guess I could create a bunch of other class files that contain the code.

Comment: Generally speaking, in terms of design and architecture, you want your controllers to be very thin and not do much.  They should be delegating most of the business logic and other logic to other classes.  So this would not necessarily be a bad thing.

Comment: Side note, where do you generally store your "other" classes?  Is there a best practice?   My MVC experience was when working with a company that had horrible conventions and I would rather not duplicate bad practices in my own work.

Comment: you shoul read this i hope it helps http://techbrij.com/service-layer-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-unit-testing

Comment: follow this series too http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

You can put all views in shared folder and then choose which wiew to render from controller methods.One of the overloads of view method takes name of the view to render.

```
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
        //
         return View("myview");
       }
```

In web forms every view has a codebehind file but mvc approach is different.You can think each action as codebehind for its view.So Controller in mvc is contains related actions for an object..

Comment: I am trying to have multiple controllers though.

Comment: Each controller would have an Index() method.  In each Index method, you'd return View(nameOfPage).  For example, you'd have PrivacyController with an Index() Method that returns View("Privacy").  It will then find the Privacy.cshtml file in /Shared and show it to the user.  This setup requires that you put your razor files in /Shared instead of /Pages.  If you want it to be able to map as you want to /Pages/ but still have individual controllers, take a look at the answer I posted below.  It's much more work, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup different routing. One way would be

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

so look for the `MapPageRoute` Method to define your own structure.

But that said, I would highly encourage you to take a closer look at the MVC pattern because especially on larger application it makes totally sense to separate things for better structure and testability. There are alot of useful guidances how to structure controllers and views and most of the have proven their usefulness for lots of devs. Especially coming from WebForms this is a different approach - but well worth that adventure.

Comment: Oh, I get that.   It's just this app is small and It seems silly to have 15 different folders with 1 view each in it.

Comment: Ok, sorry - couldn't resist to save the MVC world =) ... but with MapPageRoute you could map a couple of views from the root folder to your actions whether it's within 1 or more controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Already mentioned is the option to put your files in the /Shared folder and reference the view name in your controllers.  Another option would be to [create a custom RazorViewEngine and override the default search locations](http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/)